# LINQ group by multiple attributes and create dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, format, key

I have a list of objects from a class called `ScrewBoltPattern`.

I want to create a dictionary which contains the number of appearances of each family of `ScrewBoltPattern`. To decide if a screw belongs to a family I use some properties of that class.

To simplify this query let's say I use the properties Length and Diameter.

I want to create a Dictionary which has keys formatted like screw.Length + "_" + screw.Diameter

How can I get this?

This is what I've done so far

```
Dictionary<string, int> boltFamilyList = selectedBolts
                .GroupBy(bolt => new { bolt.Length, bolt.Diameter })
                .ToDictionary(bolt => bolt.Key, bolt => bolt.Count());
```

I need to give format to the dictionary key somewhere, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can format the key in the group by:

```
Dictionary<string, int> boltFamilyList = selectedBolts
    .GroupBy(bolt => $"{bolt.Length}_{bolt.Diameter}")
    .ToDictionary(bolt => bolt.Key, bolt => bolt.Count());
```

Your group key (and by proxy your dictionary key) will be that formatted string.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/YZDTJ95095)

Comment: And where do I specify the properties I want to use to group them?

Comment: Are you grouping by different properties to your formatted key? If that's the case, can you edit your question to reflect this?

Comment: @No, I'm not. Will that do it?

Comment: The code I've provided will group by the string value generated by `$"{bolt.Length}_{bolt.Diameter}"`, which will also be your key in the dictionary. It should work as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use an [ILookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.ilookup-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) to achieve the same goal:

```
ILookup<string, int> lookup = 
    selectedBolts.ToLookup(bolt => $"{bolt.Length}_{bolt.Diameter}");
```

and then

```
int count = lookup["12_36"].Count();
```

Comment: Which has the advantage that you don't get an exception like with a dictionary if the key isn't present and you could use other methods apart from `Count`

Comment: @Rango Indeed, + this code avoids the double enumeration (bolts and GroupBy entries) in the OP's code. The null key handling could also be handy but not in this case.

Comment: I don't think it's more efficient than OP's code. `ToLookup` needs to enumerate the list and create groups by a key like `GroupBy`+`ToDictionary` does, just in one method instead of two but with the same complexity. But it's more flexible because it allows to evaluate more than the count if you want, without creating a new dictionary.

Comment: @Rango Except than `ToDictionary` has to check whether each entries already exists. I agree, not a big deal though.

Answer (score 1):

Although you already have the solution, just want to point how you could solve it because you were really close to the solution...

```
Dictionary<string, int> boltFamilyList = selectedBolts
    .GroupBy(bolt => new { bolt.Length, bolt.Diameter })
    .ToDictionary(bolt => bolt.Key, bolt => bolt.Count());
```

in the list line you could create key:

```
.ToDictionary(bolt => $"{bolt.Key.Length}_{bolt.Key.Diameter}", bolt => bolt.Count());
```

---

If you look at the signature of the `Enumerable.ToDictionary` method you will see that the first argument is `Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector`, in your case the `TSource` is anonymous type and the `TKey` is string. All you need to do is to define mapping between `TSource` and `TKey` and that is exactly what the function `bolt => $"{bolt.Key.Length}_{bolt.Key.Diameter}"` does.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be aware of this solution as well, you may not need string formatting at all. (you can use C# 7 with value tuples)

```
Dictionary<(int length, int diameter), int> boltFamilyList = selectedBolts
    .GroupBy(bolt => (bolt.Length, bolt.Diameter))
    .ToDictionary(bolt => bolt.Key, bolt => bolt.Count());
```

And access like

```
dic.TryGetValue((10, 20), out int count);
```

Where 10 and 20 are length and diameter